# Batch script moves files successfully, but leftover files lose their extensions

Tags: batch, batch-file

I'm running the following batch script to move files into their corresponding folders:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.*) do (
move "%%a" "%%~na"
)
pause
```

For files without folders of the same name it strips their extensions. How can I modify the batch script so that the remaining files retain their extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Could be something as simple as this:

```
@echo off

set "dir=C:\Your\Directory"

for /r "%dir%" %%a in (*) do (
    if exist "%dir%\%%~na" move "%%a" "%dir%\%%~na"
)

pause
```

`for /r` looks at all files in the directory path we assigned to variable `%dir%` and assigns each file to parameter `%%a`; for each iteration where there is a subfolder (`%dir%\%%~na`) with the same name as a file (`%%~na`), you move that file into that subfolder. It will skip files that do not have a matching subfolder. If it needs to be more complex we can make it happen, but generally this is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: (1) The OP’s batch file runs naturally (albeit with problems) in the current directory.  Your script requires the user to *edit* the script to specify the name of the directory.  Why not just use `%CD%` (the name of the current directory) or even **`.`** instead of `%dir%`?  (2) The OP’s batch file ***scans*** the current directory.  Your script scans the named directory *and all subdirectories*.  There is no indication that the OP wanted this, so you should have included a warning that you were changing the behavior in this way. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) While the question didn’t mention it (perhaps the OP hasn’t discovered it yet), the original batch file has the further problem that, if `FOO` and `FOO.BAR` both exist (and are both files), then `FOO.BAR` gets renamed to `FOO`, destroying the existing `FOO`.  Your script has this same problem.  (4) While the question didn’t mention it (perhaps the OP hasn’t discovered it yet), the original batch file has the further problem that, if `FOO.BAR` is a file and `FOO` is a directory, but there is already a `FOO.BAR` file in `FOO`,  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  then the top-level `FOO.BAR` gets moved to ``FOO\FOO.BAR``, destroying the existing `FOO\FOO.BAR`.  Your script has this same problem.  (5) Minor point: You say your loop “assigns each file to parameter `%%A`”.  No, actually it assigns each file to parameter `%%a`.  Loop indices, unlike environment variables, are case-sensitive.

Comment: "could be something as simple as this" and "if it needs to be more complex we can make it happen" - as you well know having been here so long, this is not a code writing service. the point was to get them going in the right direction, which is to include `if exist`. I could have spent longer making this perfect, certainly - but that wasn't the point. it's true I mistyped when I referenced `%%A` in my description - but in the code I didn't. It's also true I could have used `%cd%`, but I didn't. you are assuming a lot in your comments, and while they're appreciated they're largely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as you probably realize, is that the command

```
move "%%a" "%%~na"
```

which expands as (for example) `move "SCHEDULE.XLSX" "SCHEDULE"`,
which is intended to move the file `SCHEDULE.XLSX`
into a folder called `SCHEDULE`,
simply *renames* `SCHEDULE.XLSX` to `SCHEDULE` if the folder doesn’t exist. 
A simple solution is

```
@echo off
for %%A in (*.*) do (
    if exist "%%~nA"\ move /-y "%%A" "%%~nA"
)
```

- As suggested by [mael'](https://superuser.com/q/1445397/150988#1445671),
  test whether the target exists before trying to move the file into it.
- Test whether the target ***directory*** exists —
  i.e., test whether the target exists *and is a directory* —
  by testing `"%%~nA"\` (with a backslash at the end, denoting a directory)
  rather than just plain `"%%~nA"`. 
  This prevents us from clobbering an existing file named `FOO`
  by moving `FOO.BAR` onto it.
- `move /-y` specifies that `move` should ask for confirmation
  before clobbering an existing file. 
  You might think that the `if exist` test covers that,
  but it doesn’t handle the case where you have a directory called `FOO`
  and files called `FOO.BAR` in *both* in the current directory and in `FOO`. 
  If you always want to overwrite the pre-existing file in the directory,
  just leave off the `/-y`. 
  If you never want to overwrite the pre-existing file
  (and you don’t want to be asked for confirmation),
  do

  ```
  if exist "%%~nA"\ if not exist "%%~nA"\"%%~nxA" move "%%A" "%%~nA"
  ```
- Changing `%%a` to `%%A` is basically a style/preference change
  (but note that it is not purely cosmetic — loop indices,
  unlike environment variables, are case-sensitive —
  if you change `%%a` to `%%A`, you must do it every time it appears). 
  Since `%~` modifiers can be aggregated — for example, `%~pnxA`
  is equivalent to `%~pA%~nA%~xA` (path, name and extension of `%A`) —
  it can be easier to read if the loop index is capitalized. 
  As an extreme example,
  in

  ```
  for %x in (.) do (something with) %~xx
  ```

  it’s not obvious that `%~xx` is the extension of `%x`.