# How to move video files to separate folders by filtering occurrence 01-03 in filenames for respective folders?

Tags: batch

Need to move video files to separate folders with a batch script.

Actually I have thousands of video files dramas so need to move each drama to separate drama folder with every drama is 40 episodes at once.

For example:

```
..\new01
        \file-01.eXt
        \file-02.eXt
        \file-03.eXt

..\new02
        \file-01.eXt
        \file-02.eXt
        \file-03.eXt

..\new03
        \file-01.eXt
        \file-02.eXt
        \file-03.eXt
```

Need to move all file contain from `01-03` to this `new01`, `new02`, `new03` separate `\folder`.

The real file names are like this:

```
Curtain.Call.S01E
Derailment.2023.ep
Joseon.Attorney.A.Morality.S01E
```

The code I’ve been using is move 10 files with different name to 10 folder not into one I need to move 10 files with different name to each separate folder.

What I tried was this code below taken from **[this](https://superuser.com/q/1445397/969781)** post by operator **[@jaime](https://superuser.com/users/1046082/jaime)**

```bash
@echo off

for %%a in (*.*) do (
     md "%%~na" 2>nul
     move "%%a" "%%~na"
    )

pause
```

Comment: I removed the link to `https://www.mirrored.to/files/0RSMUVAI/0_-_Copy.rar_links` since that site it filled with spam links and malware. Is the file just the code you posted? If so that posting is more than enough to help this question. Posting external links for a few lines of code is ridiculous.

Comment: Is the folder where the files are to be moved always the first 5 characters of the file name?

Comment: no its like this

Curtain.Call.S01E   ,
Derailment.2023.ep   ,
Joseon.Attorney.A.Morality.S01E   ,

Comment: Can you explain a little better how the files should be moved with real names of the files and to which folder, as an example...

Comment: Is this like the folder "Curtain.Call.S01E" and than you want to move all Curtain.Call.S01E*.mkv or something into that folder?

Comment: lets say ot for example i've some 10 video file with 10 differen names just place this file in one new folder with the script batch file within then click on batch file it'll move 10 files to 10 seprate folder

Comment: move all Curtain.Call.S01E*.mkv  to new folder with the same name in one folder which is Curtain.Call.S01E

Comment: hello anyone can help me ?

Comment: *..."actually i've **thousands** of video files **dramas***"..., precisely how many files dramas, episodes are 40, ok, but the dramas are how many?

Comment: Plz, understand that S12E is not much, see that in S10 39E I can understand that it would be S1239E, or S12E39, and that S01E02 would be a different layout, so these strings are not expressed in something that helps us help you. Could you post a list of names at https://pastebin.com/? Since it would be too long for here...

Comment: i've 100 dramas for example the script i use its just move 100 1st eps for each drama into 100 folders what i need is move all eps for each drama into 100 folders i've added some example here https://pastebin.com/19zHb7Zg